# Kinect Openni build errors - XnDeviceSensorV2

Tags: kinect, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

When I was trying to install the Openni for kinect, I ran into a build error

make[3]: *** [../../Bin/Release/libXnDeviceSensorV2.so] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vin/drivers/ps_engine/build/ps_engine/Platform/Linux-x86/Build/XnDeviceSensorV2' make[2]: *** [XnDeviceSensorV2] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/vin/drivers/ps_engine/build/ps_engine/Platform/Linux-x86/Build'
make[1]: *** [installed] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vin/drivers/ps_engine'
make: *** [ps_engine_lib] Error 2

Could somebody help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11435/kinect-openni-build-errors---xndevicesensorv2/) by [Vinayak](https://answers.ros.org/users/1174/vinayak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-10-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered in http://answers.ros.org/question/2431/kinect-openni-build-errors-xndevicesensorv2#4084

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1